# Deploying custom website onto clients hosting

Tags: php, apache, security, deployment, hosting

I have developed a website application that includes a custom built CMS and PayPal payments etc...

My client already has hosting for his main website via the developer of that site.

I wish to host the new application under a subdomain such as:

application.website.com

I have reservations about storing my complete source code on the other web designers server.

Is there a way that the code can remain on my server but with the required subdomain or somehow password protect the folder?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to store your source code on your server and use the PHP [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function to get the pages on your client's website to use the code on your server. I've not tried this so it may not be possible for PHP to communicate between two servers like this, but give it a go and see what happens.

Comment: Ended up pointing the subdomain over to my IP address and hosting it on my VPS.